# How can I get system load/cpu usage from Java?

Tags: java, linux, load, multicore

Normally I call in bash "mpstat 1".
Is there an equivalent Java library to aviod calling bash and parsing mpstat output?

Comment: See [
How to monitor the computer's cpu, memory, and disk usage in Java?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the average for the last minute via [the management API.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getSystemLoadAverage())