# how to cpu scavenging in Java?

Tags: java, user-input, cpu-usage

My program is a distributed software for a small laboratory. It is written in java but because during daytime the computers are used, I have to manually restart it in the evening. I would solve the problem by starting it from a service every time the computer is started but I need a mechanism to detect:
1) user input(mouse, keyboard etc.)
2) user logon

Detecting any user input from java it is not possible.  Is there any framework for something like this?

Comment: Have you considered running it as a daemon and scheduling it to start and stop when desired?

Comment: Anyhow - detecting user input directed to other programs is not supposed to be possible - it would be a major security hole. Would a timed service (between 20:00 and 04:00 for example) be acceptable?

Comment: Couldn't you just leave it running at minimum priority, also during daytime?

Comment: there are hours during daytime when the labs are free and i don't know them.

Comment: the best solution i found is getting the user activity using JNA. Using this it is possible to compute user idle time.

Answer (score 2):

Detecting user input from Java **is** possible, but not with standard tecnologies. Considering the excellent example of [aTunes](http://www.atunes.org/), you can do it using, depending upon your platform

- [JIntelliType](http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/index.html) on Windows
- [JXGrabKey](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxgrabkey/) on Linux

Considering your other question, I would use native abilities of client OSes to better handle your problem. First thing is to make your Java process lower priority. This way, it will run all time long, without having the user blocked by it. I would also force this program to stop when CPU load is over a given target. This can be achieved using JMX, as [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java) explains.

Comment: I fully agree with the CPU load approach. After all, the computer might be doing something important even when no key is pressed.