# Monitor System CPU, memory, disk I/O and network usage at diff frequency

Tags: java, network-monitoring, sigar

I need to monitor the CPU, N/w , memory and Disk I/O usage of a computer . Currently I'm using Ubuntu and will be running this using a Java code.

Also the monitoring frequency/ sampling interval must be customisable. I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java). There's no mention of network stats but for SIGAR API.

I'm looking at something lightweight. I'm having two things on my mind to do this:

1. running a shell script from my java code which formats the o/p . If so, which command should I use? Top gave only the stats process wise.
2. Use SIGAR API. but can the sampling rate be set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install prstat, iostat, pidstat packages for linux and get all info using commandline. Use java's processbuilder to execute these commands in shell and capture the output in a file so that it can be used for future processing. A word of caution, writing continuously into the same file is not a good idea with these commands (control the info by specifying polling interval and number of polls using command' options).

Hope this helps.

PS: btw take a look at nagios.

Comment: @Iyer: Yep, I tried using Nagios but the display on the browser didn't suit the purpose of app. Also, I've tried using munin plugins as well.

Comment: Oh thats interesting..
If you want to do this in programmatic manner then using the cmdline tools is best.