# How to find load capacity of the processor?

Tags: java, load, operating-system, jmx, processor

Hi for the past few days, I started working on JMX. Am not sure how to derive an mathematical formula to find 'the maximum amount of load that a processor can support' by computing various other factors using JMX (using Java program). Can anyone please suggest me how to derive an mathematical formula to find the maximum amount of load that a processor can support. Or is there any inbuilt function to find that.? Is it really possible to do the same using JMX or i need to shift to some other method?

Comment: How do you define load? The unix-style definition, based on process queues?

Comment: Am looking for a java program to find the load of the running system

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to monitor the computer's cpu, memory, and disk usage in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java)

Comment: No i already saw that post. That is slightly similar. but I didn't found what am exactly searching for.

Comment: You want a mathematical formula about the `the maximum amount of load that a processor can support` without exactly defining what `load` is? And what does "support" mean there?

Comment: it mean that the maximum amount of load that a processor can bear. That is the processor can execute all the incoming the request successfully, without going into system crash.

Answer (score 3):

You can Use [javamelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) to find out Memory usage, CPU usage, and Http session Usage like Below:
[image]
or you can use [SIGAR](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home), it provides a portable interface for gathering system information.

**Edit:** For your scenario you can use [Class ManagementFactory](http://minitorn.tlu.ee/~jaagup/kool/java/abiinfo/docs7/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html).

> The platform MBean server was introduced in the Java 2 Platform,
>   Standard **Edition 5.0**, and is an MBean server that is built into the
>   Java Virtual Machine (`Java VM`). The platform MBean server can be
>   shared by all managed components that are running in the Java VM. You
>   access the platform MBean server using the
>   `java.lang.management.ManagementFactory` method `getPlatformMBeanServer`.

Documentaion:  [management_mxbeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/mxbeans.html)

Comment: Is javamelody or SIGAR can be used inside the java program to do decision making..? Because i want to find the cpu load inside the java program so that i can make decision making with those results..

Comment: added Update to use ManagementFactory.

Comment: sorry as am new to this ManagementFactory, i dont know how to use it in my program. Can you please suggest some tutorials with sample code on how to use 'Class ManagementFactory'...

Comment: see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/mxbeans.html).