# How to get CPU, RAM and Network-Usage of a Java7 App

Tags: java, networking, cpu, java-7, ram

I found this older article [how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java)
and wated to ask, if there is something new in java 7. I want to get the current CPU-, RAM- and netzwork-Usage of my App periodically. It has to work for linux (mac) and windows. The data does not have to be extremely detailed, 3 values would be enough (cpu: 10%, Ram 4%, Network 40%). Would be cool if the data is just for the app and not the whole os-system, however this would work, too.

Thank's for help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

answering my own question ;P some code i have written...

NetworkData:

```
public class NetworkData {

    static Map<String, Long> rxCurrentMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    static Map<String, List<Long>> rxChangeMap = new HashMap<String, List<Long>>();
    static Map<String, Long> txCurrentMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    static Map<String, List<Long>> txChangeMap = new HashMap<String, List<Long>>();
    private static Sigar sigar;

    /**
     * @throws InterruptedException
     * @throws SigarException
     * 
     */
    public NetworkData(Sigar s) throws SigarException, InterruptedException {
        sigar = s;
        getMetric();
        System.out.println(networkInfo());
        Thread.sleep(1000);     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SigarException,
            InterruptedException {
        new NetworkData(new Sigar());
        NetworkData.startMetricTest();
    }

    public static String networkInfo() throws SigarException {
        String info = sigar.getNetInfo().toString();
        info += "\n"+ sigar.getNetInterfaceConfig().toString();
        return info;
    }

    public static String getDefaultGateway() throws SigarException {
        return sigar.getNetInfo().getDefaultGateway();
    }

    public static void startMetricTest() throws SigarException, InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            Long[] m = getMetric();
            long totalrx = m[0];
            long totaltx = m[1];
            System.out.print("totalrx(download): ");
            System.out.println("\t" + Sigar.formatSize(totalrx));
            System.out.print("totaltx(upload): ");
            System.out.println("\t" + Sigar.formatSize(totaltx));
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

    }

    public static Long[] getMetric() throws SigarException {
        for (String ni : sigar.getNetInterfaceList()) {
            // System.out.println(ni);
            NetInterfaceStat netStat = sigar.getNetInterfaceStat(ni);
            NetInterfaceConfig ifConfig = sigar.getNetInterfaceConfig(ni);
            String hwaddr = null;
            if (!NetFlags.NULL_HWADDR.equals(ifConfig.getHwaddr())) {
                hwaddr = ifConfig.getHwaddr();
            }
            if (hwaddr != null) {
                long rxCurrenttmp = netStat.getRxBytes();
                saveChange(rxCurrentMap, rxChangeMap, hwaddr, rxCurrenttmp, ni);
                long txCurrenttmp = netStat.getTxBytes();
                saveChange(txCurrentMap, txChangeMap, hwaddr, txCurrenttmp, ni);
            }
        }
        long totalrxDown = getMetricData(rxChangeMap);
        long totaltxUp = getMetricData(txChangeMap);
        for (List<Long> l : rxChangeMap.values())
            l.clear();
        for (List<Long> l : txChangeMap.values())
            l.clear();
        return new Long[] { totalrxDown, totaltxUp };
    }

    private static long getMetricData(Map<String, List<Long>> rxChangeMap) {
        long total = 0;
        for (Entry<String, List<Long>> entry : rxChangeMap.entrySet()) {
            int average = 0;
            for (Long l : entry.getValue()) {
                average += l;
            }
            total += average / entry.getValue().size();
        }
        return total;
    }

    private static void saveChange(Map<String, Long> currentMap,
            Map<String, List<Long>> changeMap, String hwaddr, long current,
            String ni) {
        Long oldCurrent = currentMap.get(ni);
        if (oldCurrent != null) {
            List<Long> list = changeMap.get(hwaddr);
            if (list == null) {
                list = new LinkedList<Long>();
                changeMap.put(hwaddr, list);
            }
            list.add((current - oldCurrent));
        }
        currentMap.put(ni, current);
    }

}
```

CPU-Data:

```
public class CpuData {
    private static Sigar sigar;

    public CpuData(Sigar s) throws SigarException {
        sigar = s;
        System.out.println(cpuInfo());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, SigarException {
        new CpuData(new Sigar());
        CpuData.startMetricTest();
    }

    private static void startMetricTest() throws InterruptedException, SigarException {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while(true) 
                BigInteger.probablePrime(MAX_PRIORITY, new Random());
            };
        }.start();
        while(true) {
            String pid = ""+sigar.getPid();
            System.out.print(getMetric(pid));
            for(Double d:getMetric()){
                System.out.print("\t"+d);
            }
            System.out.println();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }       
    }

    public String cpuInfo() throws SigarException {
        CpuInfo[] infos = sigar.getCpuInfoList();
        CpuInfo info = infos[0];

        String infoString = info.toString();
        if ((info.getTotalCores() != info.getTotalSockets())
                || (info.getCoresPerSocket() > info.getTotalCores())) {
            infoString+=" Physical CPUs: " + info.getTotalSockets();
            infoString+=" Cores per CPU: " + info.getCoresPerSocket();
        }

        long cacheSize = info.getCacheSize();
        if (cacheSize != Sigar.FIELD_NOTIMPL) {
            infoString+="Cache size...." + cacheSize;
        }
        return infoString;
    }

    public static Double[] getMetric() throws SigarException {
        CpuPerc cpu = sigar.getCpuPerc();
        double system = cpu.getSys();
        double user = cpu.getUser();
        double idle = cpu.getIdle();
//      System.out.println("idle: " +CpuPerc.format(idle) +", system: "+CpuPerc.format(system)+ ", user: "+CpuPerc.format(user));
        return new Double[] {system, user, idle};
    }

    public static double getMetric(String pid) throws SigarException {
        ProcCpu cpu = sigar.getProcCpu(pid);
//      System.out.println(sigar.getProcFd(pid));
//      System.err.println(cpu.toString());
        return cpu.getPercent();
    }

}
```

RAM-Data:

```
public class RamData {

    private static Sigar sigar;
    private static Map<String, Long> pageFoults;

    public RamData(Sigar s) throws SigarException {
        sigar = s;
        System.out.println(getMetric().toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SigarException,
            InterruptedException {
        new RamData(new Sigar());
        RamData.startMetricTest();
    }

    public static void startMetricTest() throws SigarException,
            InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            Map<String, String> map = RamData.getMetric("" + sigar.getPid());
            System.out.println("Resident: \t\t"
                    + Sigar.formatSize(Long.valueOf(map.get("Resident"))));
            System.out.println("PageFaults: \t\t" + map.get("PageFaults"));
            System.out.println("PageFaultsTotal:\t" + map.get("PageFaultsTotal"));
            System.out.println("Size:    \t\t"
                    + Sigar.formatSize(Long.valueOf(map.get("Size"))));
            Map<String, String> map2 = getMetric();
            for (Entry<String, String> e : map2.entrySet()) {
                String s;
                try {
                    s = Sigar.formatSize(Long.valueOf(e.getValue()));
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    s = ((int) (double) Double.valueOf(e.getValue())) + "%";
                }
                System.out.print("  " + e.getKey() + ": " + s);
            }
            System.out.println("\n------------------");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getMetric() throws SigarException {
        Mem mem = sigar.getMem();
        return (Map<String, String>) mem.toMap();
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getMetric(String pid)
            throws SigarException {
        if (pageFoults == null)
            pageFoults = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        ProcMem state = sigar.getProcMem(pid);
        Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>(state.toMap());
        if (!pageFoults.containsKey(pid))
            pageFoults.put(pid, state.getPageFaults());
        map.put("PageFaults", ""
                + (state.getPageFaults() - pageFoults.get(pid)));
        map.put("PageFaultsTotal", ""+state.getPageFaults());
        return map;
    }
}
```

PROCES-Data:

```
public class ProcessData {

    private static Sigar sigar;

    public ProcessData(Sigar s) throws SigarException {
        this.sigar = s;
        System.out.println(getMetric().toString());
        System.out.println(getMetric(getPidString()).toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SigarException {
        new ProcessData(new Sigar());
        System.out.println(ProcessData.getMetric());
        System.out.println(ProcessData.getMetric(getPidString()));
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getMetric() throws SigarException {
        ProcStat state = sigar.getProcStat();
        return (Map<String, String>) state.toMap();
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getMetric(String pid) throws SigarException {
        ProcState state = sigar.getProcState(pid);
        return (Map<String, String>) state.toMap();
    }

    public static long getPid() {
        return sigar.getPid();
    }

    public static String getPidString() {
        return ""+sigar.getPid();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi I am trying to get RamDATA using your code. Kindly explain difference between resident and size of memory

Answer (score 1):

Not much has changed since then unless it was done by another group.
below are some of the significant changes that were included in Java 7 SE. Sadly none of them are what you are looking for.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html

javamelody i have used before it is pretty simple and I was able to get it running in a short amount of time
https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/
http://demo.javamelody.cloudbees.net/monitoring

below is another alternative
https://github.com/oshi/oshi

**OSHI WILL NOT GIVE YOU NETWORK USAGE OR LATENCY PER PROCESS**

Check This :

[Java (Windows) - By process id, get memory usage, disk usage, network usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474799/java-windows-by-process-id-get-memory-usage-disk-usage-network-usage/63961626#63961626)

Comment: thanks for the link :) however, i use and need the changes of java7!

Comment: those are the changes that were made from Java 6 to Java 7. Im not sure i understand what your looking for.

Comment: yeah, the post is from 2011, just was asking if there is something new... that means the best solution in this post was "SIGAR API"

Comment: thx @Bob Sinclar, i am using sigar! it is really great and easy to code... i am new to the forum. probably my questions are to hard to answer, too.

Comment: Sigar seems to have problems working on 64 bits machines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405832/sigar-1-6-4-is-useless-exception-access-violation

Answer (score 1):

why cant you just use like bellow,

```
  try {
      for (String ni : sigar.getNetInterfaceList()) {         
        NetInterfaceStat netStat = sigar.getNetInterfaceStat(ni);   
        total+=netStat.getRxBytes();        
      }
    } catch (SigarException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

what is the **difference**???

Comment: its long time ago, but i think it was because of internal communication... i just wanted to know what is going in and out of the machine... that means only communication over real hardware interfaces... just try it out, you will see what i mean... however, i am interested in your improvements

Comment: i ran the code you wrote and compare the result with DUMeter. But the results are different.

Comment: then pls post a better code :) the simple code wosn't the solution for me... propably the sigar code changed

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Metrics java library: http://metrics.codahale.com/

It comes with Sigar integration: https://github.com/cb372/metrics-sigar