# CPU load with play framework

Tags: java, performance, playframework, playframework-1.x

Since a few days, on a system which has been in development for about a year, I have a constant CPU load from the play! server. I have two servers, one active and one as a hot spare. In the past, the hot-spre server showed no load, or a neglectable load. But now it consumes a constant 50-110% CPU (using top on Linux).

Is there an easy way to find out what the cause it? I don't see this behavior on my MacBook when debugging (usually 0.1-1%).This is something that only happened in the past few days as far as I am aware.

This is a status print of the hot-spare. As can be seen no controllers are queried apart from the scheduled tasks (which do not perform on this server due to a flag, but are launched):

```
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.2.4, http://www.playframework.org
~ framework ID is prod-frontend
~
~ Status from http://localhost:xxxx/@status,
~
Java:
~~~~~
Version: 1.6.0_26
Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre
Max memory: 64880640
Free memory: 11297896
Total memory: 29515776
Available processors: 2

Play framework:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Version: 1.2.4
Path: /opt/play
ID: prod-frontend
Mode: PROD
Tmp dir: /xxx/tmp

Application:
~~~~~~~~~~~~
Path: /xxx/server
Name: iDoms Server
Started at: 07/01/2012 12:05

Loaded modules:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
secure at /opt/play/modules/secure
paginate at /xxx/server/modules/paginate-0.14

Loaded plugins:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
0:play.CorePlugin [enabled]
100:play.data.parsing.TempFilePlugin [enabled]
200:play.data.validation.ValidationPlugin [enabled]
300:play.db.DBPlugin [enabled]
400:play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin [enabled]
450:play.db.Evolutions [enabled]
500:play.i18n.MessagesPlugin [enabled]
600:play.libs.WS [enabled]
700:play.jobs.JobsPlugin [enabled]
100000:play.plugins.ConfigurablePluginDisablingPlugin [enabled]

Threads:
~~~~~~~~
Thread[Reference Handler,10,system] WAITING
Thread[Finalizer,8,system] WAITING
Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system] RUNNABLE
Thread[net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@449278d5,5,main] WAITING
Thread[Timer-0,5,main] TIMED_WAITING
Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0,5,main] TIMED_WAITING
Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1,5,main] TIMED_WAITING
Thread[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2,5,main] TIMED_WAITING
Thread[jobs-thread-1,5,main] TIMED_WAITING
Thread[jobs-thread-2,5,main] TIMED_WAITING
Thread[jobs-thread-3,5,main] TIMED_WAITING
Thread[New I/O server boss #1 ([id: 0x7065ec20, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9001]),5,main] RUNNABLE
Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main] RUNNABLE
Thread[New I/O server worker #1-3,5,main] RUNNABLE

Requests execution pool:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Pool size: 0
Active count: 0
Scheduled task count: 0
Queue size: 0

Monitors:
~~~~~~~~
controllers.ReaderJob.doJob(), ms.         ->      114 hits;      4.1 avg;      0.0 min;    463.0 max;
controllers.MediaCoderProcess.doJob(), ms. ->     4572 hits;      0.1 avg;      0.0 min;    157.0 max;
controllers.Bootstrap.doJob(), ms.         ->        1 hits;      0.0 avg;      0.0 min;      0.0 max;

Datasource:
~~~~~~~~~~~
Jdbc url: jdbc:mysql://xxxx
Jdbc driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Jdbc user: xxxx
Jdbc password: xxxx
Min pool size: 1
Max pool size: 30
Initial pool size: 3
Checkout timeout: 5000

Jobs execution pool:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Pool size: 3
Active count: 0
Scheduled task count: 4689
Queue size: 3

Scheduled jobs (4):
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
controllers.APNSFeedbackJob run every 24h. (has never run)
controllers.Bootstrap run at application start. (last run at 07/01/2012 12:05:32)
controllers.MediaCoderProcess run every 15s. (last run at 07/02/2012 07:10:46)
controllers.ReaderJob run every 600s. (last run at 07/02/2012 07:05:36)

Waiting jobs:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
controllers.MediaCoderProcess will run in 2 seconds
controllers.APNSFeedbackJob will run in 17672 seconds
controllers.ReaderJob will run in 276 seconds
```

Comment: Is your server under Linux ? Did you try to reboot your server ? because you may be hit by the `leap second` linux kernel bug (http://it.slashdot.org/story/12/07/01/1920217/leap-second-bug-causes-crashes)

Comment: Spot-on! Everything is back to normal after a reboot. If you like to answer the question then I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your server is running under Linux, you may be hit by the [Leap Second bug](http://it.slashdot.org/story/12/07/01/1920217/leap-second-bug-causes-crashes) which appears last week-end.

This bug affects the Linux kernel (the Thread management), so application which uses threads (as the JVM, mysql etc...) may consume high load of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jdk 1.7 should be easy as they added this feature have look at my other related answer -> [How to monitor the computer's cpu, memory, and disk usage in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java/13034111#13034111)