# System Performance using Java

Tags: java

I want to find usage of every available processor in system using Java.I have got the number of available processors in system using following:

```
com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory().getOperatingSystemMXBean().getAvailableProcessors();
```

But not able to find usage of every available processor.
Please suggest some solution.Also i need hard disk usage in a system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SIGAR API](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) for this

or you can try this to find the CPU and RAM usage.

```
  import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
  import java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
  import java.lang.reflect.Method;
  import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

  private static void printUsage() {
   OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
   for (Method method : operatingSystemMXBean.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
   method.setAccessible(true);
  if (method.getName().startsWith("get") 
    && Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
        Object value;
    try {
        value = method.invoke(operatingSystemMXBean);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        value = e;
    }
    System.out.println(method.getName() + " = " + value);
    } 
 }
}
```

Check out this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java)