# Monitoring System performance(Windows) though Java Program

Tags: java, windows, cpu-usage

I need to monitor CPU usage of the system(Windows) every week and at a particular point of day and extract the specific data onto an excel sheet.

Do we have any specific API in Java available for monitoring system performance not just the JVM performance under which the program is executing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to monitor the computer's cpu, memory, and disk usage in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this thread it should contain the answer you are looking for

[How to monitor the computer's cpu, memory, and disk usage in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java)

Comment: Thanks pulasthi for sharing the link of the thread.It is exactly what is needed.