# Finding the average CPU usage for Windows machine in Java

Tags: java, cpu-usage

I have searched all over the internet for about two days now. I have found a lot about how to find the CPU usage using VB and anything in the .NET framework. I am not using the .NET framework so these are irrelevant, I feel.

What I really need is results similar to the ones shown in the "CPU Usage" section in a Windows Task Manager under the "Performance" tab. If I could find a way to mimic that calculation, then that is exactly what I am looking for. I need the percentage of CPU Usage.

Obviously, Java is not the ideal language for finding the CPU usage of a computer, but that is the language I am using and I have been able to get everything else I need about the computer except this.

I am using Windows 7 with Java version 7 update 21. Eclipse is my IDE.

This is my first time posting a question on here, so if I have left anything out or something is not clear, please ask and I will do my best to explain more of what I mean.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java possible duplicate

Comment: @DGomez I tried using the SIGAR API that is mentioned in that answer that you posted, and I was able to get the memory of the computer and a few other things, but I am still not sure how to get the average CPU Usage. Maybe I just need some help in SIGAR API. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this; one is to run a command-line tool and parse the output. On Windows 7, you can run

```
c:\Windows\system32\typeperf "\processor(_total)\% processor time"
```

Try it -- it prints a few lines of sampled CPU load data.

Another way is to use [`OperatingSystemMXBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) .

Comment: That is a very nice command! Since it causes the output to come out continually, how could I change it to just out put one line only when I call it?

Comment: You can add "-sc 1" to print just one sample.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you for responding so quickly. I have marked this as the answer. I am going to parse through the output, as you said.

Comment: The `OperatingSystemMXBean` method does not work on my Windows 8 machine. I like your command-line solution.