# CPU Load in Windows 8

Tags: java, load, cpu

I want to display CPU Load through my Java Program, I'm using this method:

```
import com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
public class cpuload{
    public static void main(String []args){
        OperatingSystemMXBean cpu = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(OperatingSystemMXBean.class);

        System.out.println(cpu.getProcessCpuLoad());

    }
}
```

but its display always `-1.0`.
I am using Windows 8 and Java version is 1.7.0_40 64bit.

Comment: I'll just leave this here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781087/using-operatingsystemmxbean-to-get-cpu-usage

Comment: thanx @Alex but m run ur code also its showing the same result -1.0

Answer (score 0):

You need give the OperatingSystemMXBean enough time to gather CPU usage information. I think, in your example it doesn't have time to gather information