# How to collect performance/profiling data as of JVM startup

Tags: java, scala, jvm

I'd like an automation process to run a data crunching java program with a profiler, or otherwise in a way that will dump typical JVM performance information about resource usage and GC - to a data file. It means a human process like "run the program" --> "start the tool" --> "attach to JVM" --> "select save..." won't fit.

So which of the various JVM profiling or performance tools may have an option to make this kind of attachment on JVM startup?

Or is there alternatively a library that I can include in my application, arriving at the same end result — of having saved performance/profiling data — perhaps by calling its api from within my program?

Comment: The scenario is one of a program that performs a task then finally exits, not an always on server, in case it's not clear in the question...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out YourKit api: https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/api/index.html

Comment: Thanks but obviously in of itself, this is not useful/helpful.. navigating the YourKit api doesn't clearly yield the way to go around it nor suggest this can be done with it. [This piece of the documentation](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/local_profiling.jsp) actually suggests it cannot be done with YourKit outside an IDE.