# How to get periodic heap dumps for my java program at regular intervals in csv format (without jprofiler)

Tags: java, heap-memory, jmx, visualvm, java-memory-model

I was wanting to get heap dumps for my generic java application at regular intervals as csv files. Let's say I have a program

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Code to be profiled
  }
}
```

I wanted to check heap dumps at regular intervals after running the program and generate a csv as below

```
Time  Committed size    Free size   Used size
0.0     251392000       235881000   15511000
1.0     456704000       264288000   192416000
2.0     1024000000      756641000   267359000
3.01    1035776000      217595000   818181000
4.01    1494528000      153111000   1341417000
5.02    1444352000      1235099000  209253000
6.02    1546240000      1185698000  360542000
```

This looks like the information which is fed to visualvm/jprofiler etc. for them to generate  memory dump charts.

I could achieve it quite easily programatically(through cmd line and jprofiler api) using jprofiler with jcontroller and jpexport , but I haven't been able to figure out how to do the same with other similar tools like visualvm , jmap etc.

What I am looking for is a programatic way to profile a java program (here Test.java) without involving the GUI at all. There is a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136880/saving-visualvm-information-as-data) , but the solution suggested is that of Tracer plugin for visualvm which will again involve using the GUI. The closest solution I have found yet is to use JMX like in the given example [here](https://dzone.com/articles/retrieving-jmx-information) , but I couldn't get it to work for me.

Is there a way to achieve this for me ? As a side note I am using Java SE 8 on a mac.

Comment: This is neither, a heap dump nor a csv file. Besides that, when you tried JMX but “couldn't get it to work”, you should show what you have tried and which problems arose.