# CPU usage of a program in java

Tags: java, cpu

I created a program in java and I want to know its CPU usage when it is being run. Is there any function? Can you help me please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Use the tools in your operating system, say: in Windows you can see this information in the task manager, or in Linux use the `top` command.

Comment: I think he wants to do it programatically.

Comment: @JBentley that's possible, yes. I'm just providing a simpler alternative, it might be enough to meet the OP's needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running `jconsole`, it will give you these statistics for all currently running Java applications. It can be found in the `bin` directory of your Java installation.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information) might be useful. The link will take you to an older post with a similar problem.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Sorry... what's the difference? I'm relatively new to SO

Comment: An answer contains a solution to the problem. Anything else should be a comment.

Comment: Providing a link is not really an answer, it should be posted as a comment in the question. Now if you add some additional information, an explanation, or some code, then that should be posted as an answer. As it is, this answer is risking getting downvoted (not by me, but who knows if someone else decides to do it?)

Comment: Until he hits 50 reputation, he cannot just leave comments.

Comment: @SimplyPanda That doesn't change anything. Answers should not be used to circumvent the 50 reputation requirement for comments (I'm not saying the answerer deliberately did that in this case however).

Comment: @JBentley Never said he should leave answers. Merely pointing out he is incapable of leaving comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tool that comes with the java SDK called [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/features.html). It can show you much much more than just CPU usage, in real time.