# How to get cpu usage, memory available in remote system without any stub file

Tags: java, memory, cpu-usage

I'm trying to get the CPU usage,memory space available. I could able to get the details
from local system using **sigar api** [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java).
I want to get same details from any machine in the same domain.

Is it Possible to get the details **without** putting any **stub file** in the remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

I think the other way would be to do a network scan using [nmap](http://nmap.org) and try guessing it's details. 
something like this: nmap -sS -P0 -sV -O  target is the ipaddress of the computer or the range of ip addresses on your domain. [this](http://www.solutionsamir.com/20101214138/Operating-Systems/Linux-Unix/10-Cool-ways-to-use-nmap.html) should help you out.

Comment: you have completely misunderstanding me.i'm trying in java.

Comment: Ohh Sorry. but maybe you try reading this http://256.com/sources/simplejmx/ hope it helps and Sorry again.