# Mule components to check the status of the resources and integrations of the Applications

Tags: java, mule

is there any Mule components that checks the status of Application Resources like CPU, DISK, MEMORY usage and integration like JDBC, MQ

example :

```
Application : Google Chrome 
Resources :  
    CPU usage = 30%,
    DISK usage = 25%
    MEMORY usage = 19%

Integrations : 
    type : JDBC
    name : Oracle DB
    status : Connection Failed

    type : MQ
    name : Rabbit MQ
    status : Connected
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Mule transformer to load the system resources into the payload, Java code to obtain recourse info can be found here [How to monitor the computer's cpu, memory, and disk usage in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java)

Comment: hello @sky.high, base on the link above that you attached. i was kind of wondering where i could find the implementation on how to check the percentage of the cpu, disk memory usage of the application(Google Chrome).