# JavaFX - Progressbar showing CPU and memory usage

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar, javafx-8, monitoring

Is there a way to create Progress Bars that are showing CPU and memory usage on server/PC in JavaFX? I have looked everywhere but there is no information about this.

Friendly Regards
Andreas

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java

Comment: Thanks James. I've read it through but I'm not sure how to implement it to JavaFX and the Progressbars used there. Any ideas? I'm using Java 1.8. /Andreas

Comment: Poll the values from an `AnimationTimer` and update the progress bars.