# How can i see the cpu percentage usage of each thread in a java process

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu-usage

So, I have a program with multiples threads, and for some reason, I don't know why, the CPU usage increases randomly. I need to know which class or thread is using the CPU.

```
ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();

 for(Long threadID : threadMXBean.getAllThreadIds()) {
     ThreadInfo info = threadMXBean.getThreadInfo(threadID);
     logging.info("Thread name: " + info.getThreadName());
     logging.info("Thread state: " + info.getThreadState());
     long cpuTime= threadMXBean.getThreadCpuTime(threadID);
     logging.info(String.format("CPU time: %.2f s",cpuTime==0?cpuTime/1000000000d));
 }
```

I need to print something like this

```
2019-10-08 20:47:41 INFO - thread name: xxxx
2019-10-08 20:47:41 INFO - thread cpu percent: xx,x%
```

Comment: Okay, and what's the question?

Comment: i need to print the cpu usage of all threads in the process.

Comment: without commands like, h top or something like that, i dont have access to the console outsidethe aplication

Comment: Take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-do-i-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java); it covers this and a handful of other related topics.

Comment: I had already seen this post, but it did not help me