# Java method to return the OS ram usage in unix

Tags: java, linux, ram

I want to create a method to return the ram usage in the main OS NOT THE OS I tried the RunTime class and it return only the JVM ram usage, but I want it for the OS level

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get OS-level system information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/get-os-level-system-information)

Comment: Maybe this could help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-do-i-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java

Comment: both answers return the JVM ram usage I want it for the whole system

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by "ram usage...for the OS level?" The most simplistic answer is that an OS normally uses _all_ of the RAM, unless you have specially configured it not to do. A more sophisticated answer would recognize the many different ways in which a modern, demand-paged, virtual-memory OS can use RAM. For example, see the Unix [proc(5) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), and scroll down to the `/proc/meminfo` heading. What _kind_ of "ram usage" are you really interested in?

Comment: I want the use the usage in my system to auto alert me when the server have a high usage of ram, so yes I want to get the OS level usage

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need portability you could read /proc/meminfo it might be what you are looking for and should be straight forward to parse.

A word of warning though, older kernel versions may have fewer rows of information. See for details https://access.redhat.com/solutions/406773

Comment: I want the use the usage in my system to auto alert me when the server have a high usage of ram

Comment: Here an example from a system with 1.3 Gigabyte available:

grep MemAvailable /proc/meminfo
MemAvailable:    1373116 kB

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/980820/what-is-the-difference-between-memfree-and-memavailable-in-proc-meminfo