# Find CPU, disk and memory usuage of a virtual machine using Java Program

Tags: java

How to find CPU, disk and memory usage of a virtual machine using Java Program? Any API or third party library that i can use? As i want to alert my client when CPU usage is more than 75, low memory and disk space.

1) OS : Redhat 7

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Do you want a tool, which can tell you all this? or you want a lib so that you could write a tool. I am bit confused

Comment: There is a two tools called ''jstat" and "jcmd" defaulr installed with java installation . You can use them to get the information about your local JVM processes . https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html

Comment: Also refer this refrrence https://dzone.com/articles/jvm-statistics-with-jstat

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-do-i-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56143016/1161484) duplicating the answer below.

Comment: Yeah. i need a library to write a program to check the CPU, memory and Disk Usage and send warning to user if required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from [`oshi` Github Project Page](https://github.com/oshi/oshi)

> OSHI is a free JNA-based (native) Operating System and Hardware Information library for Java. It does not require the installation of any additional native libraries and aims to provide a cross-platform implementation to retrieve system information, such as OS version, processes, memory & CPU usage, disks & partitions, devices, sensors, etc.