# How to measure utilization of a device with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, utilization

Does anybody knows whether it is possible to measure utilization of a server CPU with Selenium RC? I need to know service demand on the devise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are extending Selenium's capabilities with RC, you can use your programming language's native ability to measure resource utilization. For instance, in Java, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74674/how-to-do-i-check-cpu-and-memory-usage-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is just for driving the browser.  It doesn't have tools for monitoring CPU usage on the server.

However there is a company called Dynatrace that provides tools for doing this. I think they also make it pretty easy to integrate their tools with your extant Selenium scripts. Here's their website:  http://www.dynatrace.com/en/