# How to get cpu memory consumption of a particular Thread using java?

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I get Windows cpu memory consumption of a particular Thread using java?  I want to know only the memory usage not the cpu time.

Comment: There are hints, where You should google for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74674/how-to-do-i-check-cpu-and-memory-usage-in-java

Comment: to simplify, the difference between threads and processes is that threads in a process share the same memory address space, so it can be said that the process's memory belongs to all the threads at the same time.

Comment: What is "cpu memory".  That is two different concepts.  If you want memory then remove the word CPU.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get Windows cpu memory consumption of a particular Thread using java? I want to know only the memory usage not the cpu time.

You can't.  There is no way to tie heap-memory resources created in the JVM to the thread that created it since all threads share a common heap.  There are stack memory allocated to each thread but I know of no way to determine how much stack space has been consumed by each thread.

A profiler is the best way for you to go but I don't think even they show you the owning thread.  You may be able to infer this information from the object call stack however.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do that in your code or with a tool ?

With a profiler like VisualVM, this is easy. But in Java, it is harder because the JVM treats the heap as shared not separated heaps for threads.

Comment: Yes. If you go in "Sampler", then choose "Memory", you have a tab with per thread memory allocation.