# How to find memory used by each selenium web driver test case

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium test cases when executed parallel utilize 100% cpu (5 threads)
How to find memory consumed by each thread.

Comment: Would this thread help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74674/how-to-do-i-check-cpu-and-memory-usage-in-java