# Using Python (Bash?) to get OS-level system information (CPU Speed)

Tags: python, performance, cpu-speed

I want to repeat [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information) using python. Reason is I have access to 10 nodes in a cluster and each node is not identical. They range in performance and I want to find which is the best computer to use remotely based on memory and cpu-speed/cores available.

EDIT: Heck, even just a command line interface would be useful. Any quick and dirty solutions?

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo will work. I can call it from python if i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [SIGAR](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) library which has an extensive API for collecting system data cross-platform.  It also has libraries available in many languages (Python, Java, Erlang, Ruby, etc).

Comment: I don't have root access for any installs on the nodes. Will that be an issue?

Comment: No, I've used the Java version and it was just a JAR file I dropped in place.