# Get battery level in Java

Tags: java, macos, battery

I would like to make a java app that shows the current battery level of my mac OS X.

I have read [get OS-level system information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information) and was wondering how I could modify this to make it display the current % of battery

Thanks

Comment: Is it also possible in Windows?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two options.

One is to use JNI to invoke native code to get the battery level.

The other is to invoke the application `pmset` using `System.exec` in java and parse the output. I think the arguments to retrieve the battery level is `pmset -g ps` but you better check the man page

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the Mac OS X APIs:

> You can get information about power
>   sources and UPS (uninterruptible power
>   supply) devices using the I/O Kit’s
>   power-source API located in
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers/ps.
>   The header files in this folder,
>   IOPowerSources.h and IOPSKeys.h,
>   contain methods and keys to extract
>   information about both external and
>   internal power sources. For example,
>   an application can get a list of
>   attached power sources, request
>   notifications for changes in its power
>   sources, and determine how much power
>   is left in a battery.

[edit]

You will need to use JNI to access the IOKit framework.

Comment: The question asks about java, so is there a java interface to these API's ?

Answer (score 0):

Without some OS X equivalent to /proc on linux, I doubt you'll get this done without a System.exec or a JNI call.