# Getting system info i.e graphics card, cpu, ram etc using java

Tags: java

How would I get system info using java in a java applet. I nid to use this in my gaming website to find whether the clients's system can handle the requirements of some pc games
I will really appreciate the help.

Comment: This might be helpful (not duplicate, I think): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most reasonable and light-weight way to do that would be to detect the underlying OS, and parse the output of some command line commands. (for example, `uname` and the contents of the file `/proc/meminfo` on Linux)

Answer (score 0):

Java graphics performance for games has been shown to come down to the *drivers* that the card uses, on occasions, so I doubt any of this information will be of much use to discover if the game will run OK.

It would be more useful to run a test on a fixed size rendering surface and count how many FPS can be drawn.

Comment: Nothing says that the games themselves use Java - I suspect that the games are downloadable.