# How to check memory utilization by java program?

Tags: java

Is there any native java code to check the memory utilized by the program, or the only way possible is to check memory utilized by the JVM itlself?
can this be done purely in java or we need external process to fulfill this job?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Java to get OS-level system information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information)

Answer (score 4):

I think [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `java.lang.management.MemoryUsage`, or the external tool, VisualVM (shipped with JDK).

Answer (score 1):

I personally find `java.lang.management.MemoryMXBean` to be simpler to use than `MemoryUsage`. You can get the memory used by the program as follows:

```
MemoryMXBean memoryBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
long heapMemUsed = memoryBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed();
long otherMemUsed = memoryBean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed();
long totalMemoryUsed = heapMemUsed + otherMemUsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there something that jConsole can't provide?  That shows Heap, Classes, Threads, CPU and a heck of a lot more.