# How can I get system/hardware info via Java?

Tags: java, system, jna, system-information

I need to get system and hardware info via a Java application.

I'm interested in:

- Os details;
- Processors count, names, processor load in percents;
- Memory status (total/free);
- Os process (threads) count and CPU/Memory usage for each of them;
- Network statistic (for each interface);

Is there a Java library that can do this?

Comment: "I looking for Java library for this" asking for library recommendations is (now) off topic.

Comment: @Raedwald: That's a pity. I think such a type of questions are needed. The OP formulated the request very clear and concrete. We should not be so fundamentalistic - my understanding is that the rule you are mentioning should be used mainly for **avoiding *opinion-based*** questions. However this particular question is **technical**.

Comment: For those who doubt the wisdom of the library recommendations being off-topic, just look at the quality of the answers to this question.  1) An answer that just links to other Q&A's. 2) An answer that just says *"i have used SIGAR and is a wonderful tool for getting all SysInfo programatically. +1"*.  3) A "me too" answer ... deleted.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. [Using Java to get os level system Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information) will get you started in right direction.
2. [Finding Operating System Information](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/OSInformation.shtml)

Comment: Great link! Thanks from the non-OP! Sigar looks quite impressive. Have you used this Rachel?

Comment: Thanks! I think SIGAR solves my problems.

Comment: Yes, SIGAR is indeed very useful.

Answer (score 1):

i have used SIGAR and is a wonderful tool for getting all SysInfo programatically. +1