# how to get client system info from website?

Tags: php, web-applications, benchmarking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get system/hardware info via Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704073/how-can-i-get-system-hardware-info-via-java)

I'm doing a website with PHP.
one of the functionality need is to get info about the client pc..
Such as ram..graphic card..etc..
why u would say?
I will provide game download on my website..
So i need to provide the client with a way to test if the game will run on his machine
So is there a way i can do that..?

I know theres a website who do something like that: [Canyourunit](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri)
Need to do something like that..a simple one would be nice

edit: Is there any plugin, library for that?

Thanks :) Best Regards

Comment: But not quite what i need..Need to get graphic card info too

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with PHP, JavaScript or anything like that. Even Flash doesn't allow this. You could try to create a Java Applet, i think Java is able to get some system properties. Have a look at this: [How can I get system/hardware info via Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704073/how-can-i-get-system-hardware-info-via-java)

Comment: oKii..i go check that link..I know i can use unity3d to get the system info..but i'll look at that later if i got nothing else.Thanks