# How to detect the user is using the Trackpad and not the mouse in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, trackpad

I hava a Java swing application that use a 'pan-able' JComponent to display large data. When the user move the mouse wheel, I listen to these events, and update the content of the JComponent from the scrolled amount.

I would like to have a different behavior depending on whether the user is

- using a classical mouse
- using a touchpad, as the ones that can be found on modern Mac laptops.

How could I detect that the user is using the mouse wheel vs the trackpad to generate the scroll event? I am relying in java 1.6 swing, si I cannot go to javaFX.

Story behind the question: 
I just wanted to add a cool inertia feel to the scrolling event when the user use the mouse wheel. But of course, on MacOSX, the trackpad has its own inertia stuff builtin. So I wanted to decide whether I should generate the inertial movement or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java Swing is an old technology, it supports the traditional mouse wheel rotation events.

When you use the old wheel mouse, or wheel track-pad, it will read the rotation of the hardware wheel.

When you use a modern laser mouse, the mouse movement will be translated to rotation motion.

When you use a touch track-pad like the one in modern Mac laptops, the scroll gesture will be translated into rotation motion, single & double touch as left and right click (based on OS mouse-pad configuration).

You can use libraries to check the input devices in detail, in case your mouse or track-pad is connected to your computer through USB, you can try [J-USB library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18326022/2128327).

As for internal hardware, you first have to identify the type of OS, and based on that you can get [information on system and hardware in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4704086/2128327).

Finally, if your application interacts with a user, I suggest asking the user what type of mouse they're using, and store that in configuration file or something.

Comment: Ok, this is what I kind of feared. So in clear, you tell me that there is no way to know with Swing right?

Comment: @Jean-Yves yes, Swing cannot tell you that information

Comment: @Jean-Yves I know it has been a while, but I've added a **Finally** clause to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS you can get all the touchpad events in Java, I'd been searching myself for a while and just answered my own question. Leaving this here in case anyone else starts down the same rabbit hole

[What replaces GestureUtilities in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535595/what-replaces-gestureutilities-in-java-9)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

1. MetaDown is used for Right Click
2. AltDown is used for Mouse wheel

.

```
public class Exp extends JFrame {

    private String string;
    private JLabel l;

    public Exp() {
        super("Title");    
        l = new JLabel("Status");
        add(l, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        addMouseListener(new MouseClass());         
    }

    private class MouseClass extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {                
            string = String.format("Clicked %d Times", e.getClickCount());              
            if(e.isMetaDown())
                string += " With Right Mouse Button";
            else if(e.isAltDown())
                string += " With Centre Mouse Button";
            else
                string += " With Left Mouse Button";                
            l.setText(string);
        }
    }   
}
```

Also try this:

you can determine which of the Mouse buttons is pressed,by these three methods from SwingUtilities:

isLeftMouseButton

isMiddleMouseButton

isRightMouseButton

Comment: For more informaton : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isMiddleMouseButton%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29

Comment: Thanks! But actually I was interested in getting to know whether mouse wheel events are generated by the trackpad or by an actual mouse.

Answer (score 0):

***The Mouse Wheel Listener API***

Although `MouseWheelListener` has only one method, it has the corresponding adapter class — `MouseAdapter`. This capability enables an application to have only one adapter class instance for the component to manage all types of events from the mouse pointer.

```
mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent)    //Called when the mouse wheel is rotated.
```

The following code snippet is related to the mouse-wheel event handling:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MouseWheelEventDemo extends JPanel
        implements MouseWheelListener {
    JTextArea textArea;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
        try {
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MouseWheelEventDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent newContentPane = new MouseWheelEventDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MouseWheelEventDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        textArea.append("This text area displays information "
                + "about its mouse wheel events."
                + NEWLINE);

        //Register for mouse-wheel events on the text area.
        textArea.addMouseWheelListener(this);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 350));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
    }

    //Append to the text area and make sure the new text is visible.
    void eventOutput(String eventDescription, MouseWheelEvent e) {
        textArea.append(e.getComponent().getClass().getName()
        + ": "
                + eventDescription);
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }

    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        String message;
        int notches = e.getWheelRotation();
        if (notches < 0) {
            message = "Mouse wheel moved UP "
                    + -notches + " notch(es)" + NEWLINE;
        } else {
            message = "Mouse wheel moved DOWN "         
                    + notches + " notch(es)" + NEWLINE;
        }
        if (e.getScrollType() == MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL) {
            message += "    Scroll type: WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL" + NEWLINE;
            message += "    Scroll amount: " + e.getScrollAmount()
            + " unit increments per notch" + NEWLINE;
            message += "    Units to scroll: " + e.getUnitsToScroll()
            + " unit increments" + NEWLINE;
            message += "    Vertical unit increment: "
                    + scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getUnitIncrement(1)
                    + " pixels" + NEWLINE;
        } else { //scroll type == MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_BLOCK_SCROLL
            message += "    Scroll type: WHEEL_BLOCK_SCROLL" + NEWLINE;
            message += "    Vertical block increment: "
                    + scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getBlockIncrement(1)
                    + " pixels" + NEWLINE;
        }
        eventOutput(message, e);
    }
}
```

The output from MouseWheelEventDemo for a system that uses unit increments for its mouse wheel might look as follows:

```
javax.swing.JTextArea: Mouse wheel moved UP 1 notch(es)
    Scroll type: WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL
    Scroll amount: 3 unit increments per notch
    Units to scroll: -3 unit increments
    Vertical unit increment: 16 pixels
```

Comment: For complete explanation - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousewheellistener.html

Comment: Thanks! But as well, this is not the question. I just wanted to know if there is a way to know whether these events are fired by a mouse or touchpad.