# showing incorrect answer for total physical memory size in java

Tags: java

this is the code

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class MemorySize {

   public static void main(String[] args){
    com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean mxbean = 
    (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    System.out.println(mxbean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize() + " Bytes ");
```

the above code gives me the output values as `2147483647 Bytes` which is equal to `1.99 GB`. 
But the actual `installed memory(RAM) is 3.00 GB (2.30 GB usable)` .how can I get the correct value i.e, 2.30 gb. please help.

Comment: Is this running on a 32-bit JVM?

Comment: **Maybe, and I mean maybe**: probably the JVM is not allowed to use the entire `2.30 GB` of RAM available to it, and so returns the _maximum RAM that it's allowed to take_. (Still not sure... just a theroy) :-)

Comment: Possible dupicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512378/how-to-get-ram-size-and-size-of-hard-disk-using-java

Comment: This works fine on my 64-bit JVM. I suspect it's a limitation of the 32-bit address space (possibly the OS reporting to the JVM process).

Comment: @Ganesh Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

In both Windows and Linux, the `getTotalPhysicalMemorySize` method is implemented by asking the operating system.  In the case of Linux, an OpenJDK 11 JVM does that with the following C code:

```
jlong num_avail_physical_pages = sysconf(_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES);
return (num_avail_physical_pages * page_size);
```

If you check the manual page for `sysconf(3)` it says this:

> - `_SC_PHYS_PAGES`: The number of pages of physical memory.
> - `_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES`: The number of currently available pages of physical memory.

Another source tells me this:

> The value returned for `_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES` is the amount of memory the application can use without hindering any other process (given that no other process increases its memory usage).

So as you can see, this is not the total physical RAM.  Rather it is the physical RAM that is "available".

You can read the above as (also) capping the value to the amount of RAM that a process could possibly use.  With a 32 bit JVM, memory architecture considerations limit a single process to a lot less than 4GB of address space.  For Windows, the limit is around 2GB.

(This is on Linux / OpenJDK 11.  I haven't checked for other platforms and versions.)

Either way, the method returns what it returns.  AFAIK, it is the best you can get using Pure Java.

---

> "How can I get the correct value i.e, 2.30 g"

You may need to use `System.exec(...)` to run some platform-specific utility and scrape the information out of its output.  Or implement a native method that asks the OS a different question.

However, you probably should not be using your-called "correct" value for sizing your JVM.  If you try to use all of the physical RAM, you are liable to push the OS into dangerous thrashing behavior.  (You may wake up the dreaded oomkiller ... which may then pick the wrong thing to kill!)

Comment: looks like this was fixed before 2013  src: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/jdk.management/unix/native/libmanagement_ext/OperatingSystemImpl.c#l372

Comment: I think this answer got getTotalPhysicalMemorySize and getFreePhysicalMemorySize implementations mixed up. getFreePhysicalMemorySize does indeed use _SC_AVPHYS_PAGES but getTotalPhysicalMemorySize has always used _SC_PHYS_PAGES. As mentioned in the other comments I suspect this is a limitation of using a 32 bit JVM.

Comment: Yea.  32bit Java has additional constraints ... depending on the hardware architecture and the operating system, etcetera.  AFAIK there is no mainstream 32 bit OS that will allow you to create Java heap that can use all of the notional 32 bit address space, irrespective of the amount of physical RAM available.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum memory a 32bit process is allowed to take is often only 2GB.  If you use a 64bit JVM you should see the full size.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if there memory space for buffer/cache? if Yes. then 
`(com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();`
 does not give you the space used by buffer/cache. you may need to try reading

> /proc/meminfo file for proper memory information.