# Tomcat JMX CPU Usage Percentage

Tags: java, jmx, tomcat

I want to find out CPU usage (**in Percentage**) of an Apache Tomcat Server(**6.x**) using **JMX**.
There is an attribute `ProcessCpuTime` of MBean `java.lang:OperatingSystem`. But, how to calculate usage percentage from it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take the difference of two samples and divide by the time between samples.

To get a percentage, multiply by 100.

Comment: +1 Might also want to divide by the number of processors. There's a code example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information/61727#61727

Answer (score 0):

Since you will probably want to do this over time, you can use a tool like http://jmxtrans.googlecode.com/ to query Tomcat via JMX and then graph it with Graphite.

Comment: Also check jmx2graphite (https://github.com/logzio/jmx2graphite) to dump JMX into Graphite in one command line without installation nor hefty configuration