# Java Code For Pulling Hard Drive Information From Linux

Tags: java, c++, c, linux, hard-drive

I've recently been tasked with developing a program to monitor a bunch of hard drive information (serial, maker, type, etc) from multiple hard drives. In my initial research I found that this was pretty easy to do using some C# code and created a test program that way. Unfortunately, I'm required to use a linux OS which means c# is off the table.

I was curious if anyone knows, or could point me in the right direction of developing an app in Java/C/C++ that would achieve the same effect. I do know that if you use Java you have to use the JNI and you're using C/C++ at that point regardless.

Thanks.

Comment: C# is not necessarily off the table. Heard about the Mono Project?

Comment: How about `sudo fdisk -l` or `cat /proc/scsi/scsi`? No need to program anything!

Comment: @dario_ramos I have heard of the mono project, but I have to build a GUI for the program and my impression was that C# was very limited in that sense via Mono.

Ishtar I assume you mean that I just call those commands through the System?

Comment: Max: Yes, it's limited if you want to stick to WinForms or WPF. You can use Gtk, but if you wanna stick to Java, I think that @home's answer might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the exact information you need there might be no need to use JNI.

Linux make a lot of information about the hardware available in the [sysfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) and [procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) virtual filesystems.  For instance, you can find the harddisk model for the fist disk in /sys/block/sda/device/model, which you should be able to read in Java just like any other file.

Additionally you could look at the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda' and`hdparm -I /dev/sda`which both provide quite a bit of information. You can call these using`Runtime.exec()` and parse the output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any Java libraries making your life easier, but if you want to implement an OS independent solution supporting different OSes you should have a look at [java.lang.Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) which enables you to execute external processes. You could maintain a map for each OS defining the (CLI) commands for retrieving the required information. It may be easier than implementing a bunch of native calls using JNI:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("df -h");
p.waitFor();

InputStream is = p.getInputStream();

/* work with command line output... */
```

I know it's not a perfect solution, but you may want to have a look at it.

Comment: @Max: fyi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information