# Finding out system RAM via Java

Tags: java, architecture, operating-system

I am writing a program in which i need to do a minimum system RAM validation. How do i go about calculating the RAM of the machine that is executing the code in its JVM ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Java to get OS-level system information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is not possible with pure java at all.

Within the JVM you can only mesure the JVM-ram not the System RAM.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html

You'll need a piece of native code.

Comment: +1: Or run an OS command line program.  On Linux you can read the `/proc/meminfo` file

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look into Runtime class:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

but from Runtime docs:

> Returns the maximum amount of memory that the Java virtual machine
>   will attempt to use. If there is no inherent limit then the value
>   Long.MAX_VALUE will be returned

Comment: I've just found that there was a similar question already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information