# what java library class should i use to calculate memory usage in sorting algorithm?

Tags: java

is there any method that can calculate memory usage when sorting other than getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed(); from import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory; 
and im wondering getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed(); getNonHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed(); calculate the memory used in Byte? 
thx

Comment: See [Using Java to get OS-level system information](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25552/651140)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a memory profiler to measure how much memory is used.

IMHO Its best to calculate it by reading the code.  Many sorting alorithms don't use any additional heap memory. ;)

Comment: (well, technically... :-) no memory which is dependant on the size of the array being sorted) +1 for the memory profiler though, I fully agree.

Comment: Sorry, no heap space.  They all use some stack space. ;) If you are sorting an array or list, in place it shouldn't need any additional heap space no matter how big it is.