# Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()

Tags: java, windows, performance, runtime

I am trying to check the performance of a program.  I refer this post [get OS-level system information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information).  When `Runtime.availableProcessors()` executes, I get an answer of **4**.  I read [availableProcessors()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29) but it tells that this method returns number of processors

1. Can anyone explain what is mean by number of processors ?
2. Why am getting 4 as result ?

I am using Windows 7 core i5 4gp.

Comment: do you have quad core processor machine ?

Comment: or a dualcore with hyper-threading ?

Comment: Not all i3, i5 or i7 are the same. An i3 can have one or two cores with or without hyper threading. An i7 can have 4 or 6 cores. It might be useful to look up your exact model on the intel website. Here is an example. http://ark.intel.com/products/52210/Intel-Core-i5-2500K-Processor-%286M-Cache-3_30-GHz%29 Note how many options there are!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As you've read, **availableProcessors()** is a method that returns the `number of processors available to the JVM`. **4** means the number of processors currently available for JVM.

***These lines return the `number of logical cores` on Windows and in other operating systems.***

On a computer with a **quad-core Core i7** supporting **Hyper-Threading**, it will return **8**.

On a computer with a **quad-core Q6700**, this method will return **4**.

Comment: This returns the number of physical cores, not logical ones.
`Aug 02, 2023 11:51:48 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.19
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
8`

However this machine had 16 logical cores. only 8 physical cores

Answer (score 22):

The number of processors is basically the number of execution engines capable of running your code. One of the i5 variants is a 4-core CPU, the i5-7 series. These may be physically distinct processors (even though they exist inside the same chip) or they may be logical processors when you're using hyper-threading.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i5 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading for more detail.

Answer (score 3):

You have a [multi-core processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) (in your case, it looks like it's [Lynnfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynnfield_%28microprocessor%29)). Each core counts as a separate CPU (a separate processor) for the purpose of the information, since each core can execute instructions at the same time as the others.

Answer (score 3):

It gives no of cores that are available to jvm process. it may larger that actual if hyper threading is enable.

Comment: i mean core, cores are separate cpu that can perform task in parallel,

Answer (score 0):

In this context, a "processor" is "hardware capable of independent execution", ie a cpu *core*.

It is not the "processor package" - the single hardware unit you buy (that is actually 4 independent CPUs in one package)