# Is it possible to get information about an item in the Processes tab of the Task Manager (Windows)

Tags: java, windows, operating-system, taskmanager

I am wondering if it is possible to get information (like memory usage) about a running process which can be normally seen in the Processes tab of the Windows Task Manager.
If yes, is there any way of doing it, using java?

Comment: This might be helpful. It has a lot of information and links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has a command called `tasklist` that gives you

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
```

You can use a `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe")` to read that information.

Something like this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: @Ameoo: glad to help :) However, you might also want to look at [SIGAR APIs](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) as well