# How to get computer characteristics?

Tags: java

Is it possible to get computer characteristics? For example, I want to get processor frequency, RAM and free hdd space.

Comment: Have you done any research before posting your question?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza sorry, it's hard possible to get necessary information in search with my bad english, i don't know what i need to search sometimes

Comment: Sure, I have gone through that path some years ago. Still, I just copied *get computer characteristics* from your question title and added *java*, then did a search on google and this was in my first results: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25552/1065197

Comment: For what purpose do you need this information?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen for approximate computation of execution of the program

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for it, I will consider it next time!

Comment: You can ask about the number of cores which gives an indication of the number of threads you can have at once, but for the rest you should instead measure progress through the workload and then estimate that with the current speed the program will be done in X minutes.  Also allow the user to override the number of threads - there might be factors you did not think of.