# How to get cpu type in java?

Tags: java, processor

I want to retrieve a procesor tipe in java program(like "Ivy bridge").I look for some Sytem comand like:

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER"));
System.out.println(System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"));
System.out.println(System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"));
System.out.println(System.getenv("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"));
```

but i don't find what i want.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information

Comment: But in the link you passed me, i got memory size, not the cpu type.

Comment: You won't get "Ivy Bridge" back no matter what. It's Intel's codename for the architecture, not a product identifier. Programmatically available CPU descriptions tend to be more along the lines of "Core 2 E3500".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the registry. This can be done easily with JNA. Works for Windows only.

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util;
import static com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

    public class GetCPUInfosUsingJNA {

        // https://github.com/twall/jna#readme
        //  you need 2 jars : jna-3.5.1.jar and platform-3.5.1.jar

        public static void main(String ... args) {
          System.out.println(Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue
             (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0\\",
              "ProcessorNameString"));   
          System.out.println(Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue
                  (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                     "HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System\\CentralProcessor\\0\\",
                   "Identifier"));        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows use jawin to access win32 api and for linux distributions read /proc/cpuinfo and parse it.