# Detect hardware on client from a java web application

Tags: java, web-applications

I am creating a web application using java. I'm wondering if there is a way to detect external memory like an SD card on a client's device. Also, is Java a good language to use for an application with this functionality? Or is there something better?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information

Comment: @pss That's for a Java applet/java code on a machine. This is across the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java works on the server side (your server) and won't run on the client unless you send a Java application to the client like an Applet or a JavaFX app. If using the web application only, you're unable to accomplish this with Java, if you're using the Applet/JavaFX approach, you're able to get that info but maybe you cannot send it to the server.

IMO it would be very insecure to have such features in a web application. Imagine a web application where everyone who access to it and the web application can access to your SD card, retrieve all the contents and send them through the net to the server side, thus having access to all your info and the info of every user who access to it.