# How is the Java measure memory usage given method?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

I need to measure memory usage some sort of method. I can get Heap and nonHeap Memory size using mxBean.getHeapMemoryUsage and mxBean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage.

My question is how do we caclulate memory usage in specific method execution? (Only consider HeapMemory or both)

Comment: Very little of this makes sense, and your final sentence is self-contradictory.

Comment: calculate the memory consumed by local variable used in method.

Comment: Yes, I asked I can measure memory usage getting difference between HeapMemeory or do I have to consider Heap and nonHeap?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider only HeapMemory and not NonHeapMemoryUsage. NonHeapMemory is where Java Virtual machine keeps method codes and classes byteCode stuffs.

Here is helpful link [get OS-level system information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/get-os-level-system-information)

Note: you should consider stack memory as well, but that is very less compare to heap memory used by methods or class objects.