# Performance parameters (RAM, CPU, HDD) of a Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, memory, cpu-usage, ram

I have a question:

I have developed a Web Service that I write in Java Code using Netbeans and Tomcat. 
I would like to know some performance parameters as RAM usage, CPU and number of HDDs to size my application.
How can I know it?

Comment: which OS do you use?

Comment: I use both Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/get-os-level-system-information#25583 this link will help..

Comment: Ok Thanks, but I don't understand when I can use this code. For example, you image that I run this Web Service after that I had a request from client. I want to see during the elaborate the RAM usage, Cpu ecc... if I write this code at the end, it keeps track of this information?

Comment: Suppose if you want the server information then it should be published as a webservice for a client to query the details.