# How do I read system information in Java?

Tags: java

I am looking to write a GUI in Java that will give standardized information from the computer's hardware (for example, I want to know what my processor is, and discover that it's an Intel i7 processor, with an integrated graphics card). Are there any external libraries to download that would enable me to read this information?  Keep in mind, all I want is the name of the processor/graphics card/operating system, not anything within it.

Edit:  I understand that there is another question asking something similar, however, that question is asking about the usage of the specific parts of hardware, where I am simply looking for the names of the hardware.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `System` javadocs?

Comment: Thanks! This has a bit of what I want!  However, I have to say that it doesn't include some of the hardware pieces of information.  Any idea as to how I can get that data?  I look at the System Properties part of the Control Panel and I see the information, so I was just wondering if it was possible in Java too.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This link may be helpful for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/get-os-level-system-information