# how to get motherboard serial number on GUI (in java)

Tags: java, user-interface, motherboard

I did like to show a motherboard serial number in text field (GUI panel). I created a text field and action button. I wrote this code in action button. What mistake did i make in this code?

```
try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic baseboard get serialnumber");
        BufferedReader inn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        while (true) {

            String line = inn.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            motherboard.setText(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Sorry could not found motherboard serial!");
    }
```

Comment: You should not ignore the exception. At least write it to a log. In this case it would tell you the reason for the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get OS-level system information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/get-os-level-system-information)

Comment: it could not tell me what is exception. when i run it in console then it work well but when ever i am try it gui then not working and don't display in jTextfield

Comment: I think getting output from command line tools and parsing their info is rubbish. Get a library which is able to query WMI from Java and use that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 try
    {
        String result = null;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic baseboard get serialnumber");
        BufferedReader input
                = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result += line;
        }
        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
            System.out.println("Result is empty");
        } else
        {
            motherboard.setText(result);
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    getBufferReader("wmic logicaldisk get volumeserialnumber");
    getBufferReader("wmic csproduct get UUID");
    getBufferReader("wmic csproduct get name");
    getBufferReader("wmic CPU get ProcessorId");
    getBufferReader("wmic CPU get Architecture");
    getBufferReader("wmic CPU get NumberOfCores");
    getBufferReader("wmic CPU get ProcessorType");
    getBufferReader("wmic CPU get Revision");
    getBufferReader("wmic CPU get Family");
    getBufferReader("wmic CPU get Level");
    getBufferReader("wmic CPU get Name");
    getBufferReader("wmic CPU get SerialNumber");
    getBufferReader("wmic bios get Manufacturer");
    getBufferReader("wmic bios get Version");
    getBufferReader("wmic bios get SMBIOSBIOSVersion");
    getBufferReader("wmic bios get SMBIOSMajorVersion");
    getBufferReader("wmic bios get SMBIOSMinorVersion");
    getBufferReader("wmic bios get ReleaseDate");
    getBufferReader("wmic bios get serialnumber");
    getBufferReader("wmic baseboard get serialnumber");
    getBufferReader("wmic DISKDRIVE get SerialNumber");
    getBufferReader("wmic useraccount get name,sid");


    public static String getBufferReader(String getCode) throws IOException, Exception {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        Process processRun = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(getCode);
        BufferedReader processBuf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processRun.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = processBuf.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        return output.toString().substring(output.indexOf("\n"), output.length()).trim().replace("-", "");
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you read a `multi-line` output

```
while (true) {
    String line = inn.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
...
```

but you store always only the line which was current read in the textfield. Means previous output is overwritten.

```
...
        motherboard.setText(line);
}
```

As the last line of the output is an `empty line` your text field shows this empty line (means you don't see any output).

**edit** Below is added only for completeness.

A small method which could be used as `String serialNumber = getSerialNumber()`. It filter out the header line and the empty lines.

```
static String getSerialNumber() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("wmic", "baseboard", 
            "get", "serialnumber");
    Process process = pb.start();
    process.waitFor();
    String serialNumber = "";
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            process.getInputStream()))) {
        for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
            if (line.length() < 1 || line.startsWith("SerialNumber")) {
                continue;
            }
            serialNumber = line;
            break;
        }
    }
    return serialNumber;
}
```

Another way could be to do the filtering already on the `wmic` command and read only the first line from the output.

Either with commandlline tools provided by Windows

```
wmic baseboard get serialnumber | findstr /r /v "^$" | findstr /v "SerialNumber"
```

or using a custom `XSL` to control the output of `wmic`.

Save it as `simple.xsl`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="COMMAND/RESULTS"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and run the command as

```
wmic baseboard get serialnumber /Format:.\simple
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void serial(){
    // wmic command for diskdrive id: wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber
    // wmic command for cpu id : wmic cpu get ProcessorId
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "wmic", "bios", "get", "SerialNumber" });
        //process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "wmic", "DISKDRIVE", "get", "SerialNumber" });
       // process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "wmic", "cpu", "get", "ProcessorId" });
       //process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "wmic", "baseboard", "get", "SerialNumber" });
        process.getOutputStream().close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Activate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
    String property = sc.next();
    String serial = sc.next();
    System.out.println(property + ": " + serial);
    this.serial.setText(property + ": " + serial);
}
```

Comment: For the motherboard number, use 'baseboard'.

Comment: Could you please add an explanation as to why this is a solution.

Comment: @IronMonkey You could use the Scanner class as an alternative way of reading the process input stream, rather than BufferedReader. I never tried it using BufferedReader though, but Scanner got the job done for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an other form of Runtime.exec :

```
        String[] command = {"wmic", "baseboard", "get", "serial number"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: Often when you invoke an external command with parameters, the `exec(String)` method does not work as expected. The `exec(String[])` version is much more reliable in those cases.