# Am using i5 processor, java is showing it as sun.cpu.isalist = i486 i386 i86, is my processor information is accurate?

Tags: java, windows, architecture, operating-system, system

Using System class in java, I have read the properties of my system, and I found that one of the property is showing my processor information as follows.

```
sun.cpu.isalist = pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86
```

Does this property say my computer is using `i5` processor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get OS-level system information](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25552/5221149)

Comment: which means , java doesn't give accurate information about the processor of System, right?

Comment: What does `msinfo32` -> `System Summary` -> `Processor` say?

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz  @xmojmr