# Get System Properties in Java

Tags: java

I want to write a Java code which will print the System properties (whether machine's OS is windows or linux) on the machine it runs and store it in a variable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the question, what do you want to check exactly? Like a self check if your app can run on the computer it was started on? Do you have any specifics?

Comment: first - whether the system is Win32 or Unix? Depending on the system the logic will change of the script.

Comment: Come on. That's a -1. I even [mistyped](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+get+oeperating+system) but the first result is perfect.

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify your question, edit your question instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/get-os-level-system-information This is what I think you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get OS name:

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```

To get a list (set) of all system properties you can use:

```
System.getProperties().entrySet();
```

and to print them use:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
//and
System.out.println(System.getProperties().entrySet().toString());
```