I want help in Java on accessing device specifications
I am creating an application similar to CPU-Z to obtain the full specifications of the device, such as details of the cache, graphics card, temperature, number of cores and threads, and frequency.
The problem is that I searched for a long time and found only a little thing until I felt frustrated. Are there any offices in Java that support this? I want a code to help.
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;

public class Cpu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

        long cacheSize = osBean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize();

        System.out.println( + osBean.getVendor());
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();

        for (GraphicsDevice gd : gs) {
            System.out.println(gd.getIDstring());
            System.out.println(gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth()
                    + "x" + gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight());
        }
        System.out.println(gs[0].getConfigurations()[0].getDevice());
        System.out.println(gs[0].getDefaultConfiguration().getDevice());
        System.out.println("CACHE " + cacheSize / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) + " bytes");

        System.out.println(osBean.getAvailableProcessors());

        System.out.println((osBean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize()) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) + " bytes");

        System.out.println(osBean.getProcessCpuLoad());
        System.out.println(osBean.getProcessCpuTime());
        System.out.println(osBean.getVersion());
        System.out.println(osBean.getArch());
        System.out.println(osBean.getName());
        System.out.println(osBean.getSystemCpuLoad());

    }

}


Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be helpful if you focused this question to just one specific "how do I" question. Each of those stats may be in different places, and people may not know what CPU-Z is (I don't, for example).

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the
How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to
reproduce the issue. See also How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/get-os-level-system-information

Whoever it was proposed that bizarre edit which I rejected, please don’t. You wilfully destroyed most of the useful information in the question. You don’t know better than the OP what he wants.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Here is an example with the Oshi library.
Add OSHI library
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.oshi</groupId>
      <artifactId>oshi-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.6.0</version>
 </dependency>

Program
import oshi.SystemInfo;
import oshi.hardware.HardwareAbstractionLayer;
import oshi.software.os.OperatingSystem;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo();
        HardwareAbstractionLayer hal = si.getHardware();
        OperatingSystem os = si.getOperatingSystem();

        System.out.println(hal.getGraphicsCards());
        System.out.println(hal.getSensors());
        System.out.println(hal.getComputerSystem());
        System.out.println(hal.getProcessor());
        System.out.println(hal.getMemory());
        System.out.println(hal.getPowerSources());
        System.out.println(hal.getDiskStores());
        System.out.println(os.getFileSystem());
        System.out.println(hal.getNetworkIFs());
        System.out.println(os.getNetworkParams());
        System.out.println(hal.getDisplays());
    }
}

Please refer this link: How to make oshi.hardware.Sensors information available to get. Can it be done?
